# New browser window every new iteration

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to open every new iteration, new browser windows, when I try this code:

```
class GoogleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver')
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20)
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(30)

    def test_01_goole(self):
        for i in range(3):
            browser = self.browser
            browser.get('http://www.google.com')
            browser.close()
```

I receive:

```
WebDriverException: Message: no such session
```

Comment: You need to write `webdriver.Chrome('/home/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver')` in the loop

Comment: But I need it from setUp()

Comment: Remove browser.close() from the loop. As setup is being called once and browser which is being instantiated in setup gets closed in the first iteration of loop.